# Probability question...

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a survey, N married couples are observed (i.e. N men and N women).
A few decades later, in a follow-up survey, it was discovered that k individuals, among those who were surveyed, have died. Assuming that the deaths were random, the expected number of couple who survive is

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of a specific woman surving is $1$ minus the probability of her dying and the probability of her dying is $\frac k{2N}$.  So the probability of a her living is $1 -\frac k{2N}$.

So given a married couple the probability of the wife surviving is $(1-\frac k{2N})$. Given that of the remaining $2N-1$ people $k$ have died the *conditional* probability of her husband surviving *given* that the wife did, is $1-\frac k{2N-1}$ and the probability of a couple surving is $(1-\frac k{2N})(1-\frac k{2N-1})$.

And so of the $N$ married couples you will expect $N(1-\frac k{2N})(1-\frac k{2N-1})$ to still be intact.

The expression $N(1-\frac k{2N})(1-\frac k{2N-1})$ can be rewritten as $N(\frac {2N -k}{2N})(\frac {2N-k-1}{2N-1}) = \frac {(2N-k)(2N-k-1)}{2(2N-1)}$ but I don't know if that makes things better.

Credit to saulspatz for noticing two mistakes I made in my previous answer.

Comment: There are $2N$ people.  Also, I don't think the survivals are independent.  Once we know that the wife survived, the conditional probability of death for the remaining people, including her husband, increases.

Comment: Hmm,  you are right....

Comment: It's awesome that the same answer can be derived much simpler. Kudo to you, @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\newcommand{\chh}[2]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\\#2\end{array}\right)}N\frac{\chh{2N-2}{k}}{\chh{2N}{k}}=\frac{(2N-k)(2N-k-1)}{2(2N-1)}$.

Proof)

Let $X_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ denote whether or not $i$th couple has survived. That is

$$
X_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{if $i$th couple has survived}
\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}\right.
$$

Then the expected number of couple who survive is
$$
\mathbf{E} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{E} (X_i).
$$

This is true whether or not $X_i$ are independent since the expected value is a linear operator.

Now $\mathbf{E} X_i$ stands for the probability that $i$th couple has survived and
$$
\frac{\chh{2N-2}{k}}{\chh{2N}{k}}
$$
since the total number of ways that one can choose $k$ people out of $2N$ people is $\chh{2N}{k}$ and the total number of ways that one can choose $k$ people out of $2N-2$ people, i.e., everyone but this couple, is $\chh{2N-2}{k}$.

Note that $\chh{n}{k}$ refers to the number of ways of choosing $k$ items out of $n$ items, i.e.,
$$
\chh{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$$

Therefore, the expected number of couple who survive is
$$
\mathbf{E} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{E} (X_i)
= N \mathbf{E} X_1 = N\frac{\chh{2N-2}{k}}{\chh{2N}{k}}
=\frac{(2N-k)(2N-k-1)}{2(2N-1)}.
$$

Comment: You can simplify it to $N\frac {\frac {(2N-2)!}{k! (2N-2-k)!}}{\frac {2N!}{k!(2N-k)}}=N\frac {1}   {\frac {2N(2N-1)}{(2N-1-k)(2N-k}} =N\frac {(2N-1-k)(2N-k)} {2N(2N-1)}$.  But this seems unnecessarily complicated. The order of the couples won't matter.

Comment: @fleablood you're right. thx! yes, the order doesn't matter.